# Задать лимит строки r=1*2*3...*n

Tags: c++

Пользователь должен задать лимит строки умножения данного типа, без FOR итд.
Только goto, счетчик и if :C
Вот типа так :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int p, n,lim=1, i=1;
    cout << " Introduceti limita sirului 1*2*3...*n : " << endl;
    cin >> n; 
    E:
    p = 1 * i;
    if (lim < n)
    {
        i++;
        goto E;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " P = " << p << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1) в чём вопрос? 2) при чём тут C++?

Comment: думаю, стоит заменить `lim < n`на `i < n`  и все заработает

Answer (score 0):

У вас создаётся бесконечный цикл в `lim < n`, так как не изменяется `lim`. То есть условие `if (lim < n)` всегда `true`.

Отсюда есть два выхода.
Первый:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int p, n,lim=1, i=1;
    cout << " Introduceti limita sirului 1*2*3...*n : " << endl;
    cin >> n; 
    E:
    p = 1 * i;
    lim++;
    if (lim < n)
    {
        i++;
        goto E;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " P = " << p << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Данный способ не является разумным, так как вы вводите ещё одну операцию суммирования.

Второй:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int p, n,lim=1, i=1;
    cout << " Introduceti limita sirului 1*2*3...*n : " << endl;
    cin >> n; 
    E:
    p = 1 * i;
    if (i < n)
    {
        i++;
        goto E;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " P = " << p << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```